# Chrome Autofill

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, webforms

I have been trying to figure out why Chrome auto fills the wrong fields.  Every tutorial I have seen says to shut off but that is not a good idea since my users would have to turn off their auto-fill and that is just no a solution.  Here is the code I am using.

```
    <form class="form" action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
        <div style="margin-top: 60px;margin-bottom: 20px;color: #b30000;" class="alert alert-error"></div>
          <center>
            <?php echo($_SESSION['loginerror']);?>
            <input style="margin-top: -40px;" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" required />

            <br>
            <input style="margin-top: 0px;" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Log-In" name="submit"  style="width: 50%;margin-left: 20px;margin-top: 15px;" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" />
            <p style="margin-top: 10px;font-size: 12px;">Forgot your password? <a href="forgot.php">Click Here</a></p>
        </center>
        <br>
```

Here is a screen shot of how it appears to the user.  It is my street address.[image]

Comment: Isn't this how it looks to you? I assume your visitors don't see this on their browser? You could try adding autocomplete="off" to the input fields.

Comment: are you sure you want to post your address so publicly on the internet?

Comment: Try to "clear browser data" in your chrome browser settings. Once you cleared the saved form data in your chrome browser, these entries should disappear.

Comment: @cephei_vv it happens again once you clicked saved. Unless you're in Incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `type="email"` to give the browser a hint.

```html
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `autofill` attribute to `input`, will solve this issue

```
<input ..... autocomplete="off">
```

> **P.N:** As i know Firefox will not respond to this

[check browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff)

Comment: He specifically said _Every tutorial I have seen says to shut off but that is not a good idea_

Comment: @SourceOverflow so do you have any other methods to prevent caching. this is only the way

Comment: Why prevent caching? He wants to fix the autofill, I think.

Comment: @SourceOverflow then why he used `autocomplete="off"` in form ?? :P

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to the following

```html
<input ... type="text" name="email" required>
<input ... type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

or

```html
<input ... type="email" name="email" required>
<input ... type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```